# Cannot get my loop to keep prompting user for a score

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement

My code is nearly complete, and is functioning just fine, except I want my if statement to keep asking the user for a score. As it is right now, it asks the user for a score, and if you enter an invalid entry, it gives the line saying please try again, but then the code stops. I want it to keep prompting the user until they enter an invalid number.

```
//Variables
            double grade;
            string studentName;
            //Prompt the user for the student's name
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the student's name:");
            studentName = Console.ReadLine();
            //Prompt the user for the student's score
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the student's score between 0 and 100:");
            if (!(double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out grade)))
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry, scores entered must be numeric. Please try again");
            }
            else if (grade >=90)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} has a score of {1} which is an A.", studentName, grade);
            }
            else if (grade < 90 && grade >= 80)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} has a score of {1} which is a B.", studentName, grade);
            }
            else if (grade < 80 && grade >=70)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} has a score of {1} which is a C.", studentName, grade);
            }
            else if (grade < 70 && grade >= 60)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} has a score of {1} which is a D.", studentName, grade);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} has a score of {1} which is an F.", studentName, grade);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: use a loop you dont have one.

Comment: you can use a `do/while`

Comment: I assume you mean until they enter a *valid* number - at which point, should it print out the result then stop, or keep prompting? Also if I were marking this an exercise I wouldn't look too kindly on the amount of unnecessarily repeated code you have.

Comment: no where in your code do we see a loop, do a google search on the following and focus on the section about different types of loops `C# Basics Tutorial Loops`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an infinite `while` loop-

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the student's name:");
    studentName = Console.ReadLine();
    //Prompt the user for the student's score
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the student's score between 0 and 100:");
    if (!(double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out grade)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry, scores entered must be numeric. Please try again");
        break;
    }
    else if (grade >= 90)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} has a score of {1} which is an A.", studentName, grade);
    }
    else if (grade < 90 && grade >= 80)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} has a score of {1} which is a B.", studentName, grade);
    }
    else if (grade < 80 && grade >= 70)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} has a score of {1} which is a C.", studentName, grade);
    }
    else if (grade < 70 && grade >= 60)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} has a score of {1} which is a D.", studentName, grade);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} has a score of {1} which is an F.", studentName, grade);
    }
}
```

I included a `break` statement to break the `while-loop` if a value is entered that is not numeric (as per your `if` condition).